# как убрать ошибку из консоли если файла или адреса не существует

Tags: ajax, axios, type-error

```
axios.head('img/1.jpg')
```

**ошибка**

*HEAD http://site.com/img/1.jpg 404 (Not Found)*

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  axios.head('img/1.jpg')
} catch {}
```